# What's the best way to convert video for the BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I like to catch up on TV shows/movies etc. while I commute by watching them on my BlackBerry, and I was wondering what the best way to convert AVI/MOV files for viewing on this device might be.

I've been using the BlackBerry Video Converter (http://www.seabyrdtech.com/bbvideo)  and it works ok except that the audio playback gets out of sync with the video over a long file.

Is there anything better (windows or Linux x86)?

Comment: Please add your OS and what file format BlackBerry uses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Any Video Converter Freeware](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/)

[image]

> Free Video Converter with more than
>   4,800,000 happy users!
>
> Any Video Converter Freeware- the Free
>   Video Converter - is the most renowned
>   free video converter for converting
>   video files between various formats,
>   with fast converting speed and
>   excellent video quality. This powerful
>   free video converter application makes
>   video conversion quick and easy.

**Any Video Converter features include:**

- User-friendly interface that is easy to use.
- Converts all video formats to Apple iPod Video, Sony PSP and more
- Batch convert any video formats including avi, wmv, asf, mpg, mp4, etc.
- Support DivX and Xvid avi format as importing and exporting video
- Support default video/audio settings or user customized parameters for video and audio.
- Has the option to preview the video in real-time before conversion .
- World's fastest video conversion speed with stunning video and audio quality.
- Supports adjust many video/audio options for MP4 files. For example, video/audio sample rate, bit rate, video size..

**Input formats:**
avi, asf, mov, rm, rmvb, flv, mkv, mpg, 3gp, m4v, vob, YouTube videos and more

**Output formats:**
avi, mp4, wmv, flv, MPEG-1 and MPEG-2, mpg (PAL or NTSC), mp3, wma, ogg, aac

> "To have your favorite clips how you
>   want them, whether that's on your DVR,
>   iPod, PSP or desktop, you need the
>   right utility to convert theem into
>   the format that works for you.
>   Commercial video converter software's
>   aplenty, but there are several solid
>   free utilities that can convert your
>   video files on every operating system,
>   or if you've just got a web browser
>   and a quick clip. Put DVDs on your
>   iPod, YouTube videos on DVD, or
>   convert any video file with Any Video
>   Converter Freeware, today's top 10
>   free video rippers, encoders and
>   converters."
>   -- From Lifehacker.com

Comment: Any problems or drawbacks with this product?

Comment: I can look for some ;-) But I don't have anything to convert, so can't go try it out myself

Comment: It will nag if you want to upgrade after converting, but the conversion process is so dead easy, that you shouldn't bother about the notification

Comment: AVC seems to do the trick for me so far. It even has instructions specific to my model Blackberry: http://www.any-video-converter.com/convert-video-for-blackberry-bold-9000.php

Comment: Lol accepted with zero upvotes, glad it works anyway!

Comment: This is probably new, but they limit the videos to be 3 min in length!

Comment: That would be really crap, but I can't verify it

Comment: Just converted a 25 minute file and it works beautifully.  If this did have a 3 minute limit last year, it's gone now.  Wish I could upvote this answer more than once :D

Answer (score 2):

[SUPER (Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer).](http://www.erightsoft.net/SUPER.html)

Some times I use [Any Video Converte](http://www.any-video-converter.com/)r (free version)